# Обнуление статистики sqlite в полночь

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создаю телеграм-бота. Сам бот уже готов, теперь встал вопрос о сборе статистики. Как записывать пользователя в базу и удалять при отписке худо-бедно разобрался. Еще хотелось бы вести статистику взаимодействия с ботом, которая обнуляется раз в сутки.

На выходе хотелось получить такую стату:

1. Общее количество пользователей (это есть)
2. Количество пользователей за сутки (обнулять в полночь)
3. Количество запросов контента в боте (обнулять в полночь)
4. Среднее количество взаимодействий юзера с ботом (тут уже легко, если решить 2-ой и 3-ый пункт)

Направьте пожалуйста на путь решения. Может это легче решить вообще без sqlite? Работаю через aiogram.

Comment: В какую-то таблицу  базы данных записывать взаимодействия все пользователей с ботом (пользователь, время, тип действия... все необходимые данные), по ней потом запросами запрашивать данные за сутки. При необходимости старые данные зачищать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто! тебе всего лишь нужно написать функцию, которая обнуляет статистику. И запускать ее раз в сутки.
В этом тебе может помочь [совет от разработчиков aiogram](https://telegra.ph/Zapusk-funkcij-v-bote-po-tajmeru-11-28)